# Property 'get' does not exist on type 'IFields'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

In SPFx Webpart properties, as a cascading drop down showing all list/library from the current site, based on the selection of the list, trying to show the list fields.

```
var spListColumns = _sp.web.lists.getById(this.properties.listId).fields.filter( "ReadOnlyField eq false and Hidden eq false and TypeAsString eq 'Choice'" ).get();
```

It seems .get() is deprecated, no examples are shown in the pnp document guide to get all list fields in the @pnp/sp : 3.11.x version.

any other way to get all list fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get() does not work in PnP version 3.
Use just brackets like this `()`.

Refer below code:

```
let spListColumns = _sp.web.lists.getById(this.properties.listId).fields.filter( "ReadOnlyField eq false and Hidden eq false and TypeAsString eq 'Choice'" )();
```